# How do you correctly set a .net core 3.1 web api url for docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to set up and test an aspnetcore 3.1 web API using docker Linux containers. the container builds and runs the web API but the URL is as follows:

`https://localhost:6001/https://%7BServiceHost%7D:6001/Swagger`

It should be `https://localhost:6001/Swagger`

How should I have set up my docker file/docker-compose.yml to give the correct URL?

Docker file:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 443

COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish ApiProject -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ApiProject.dll", "--environment=Development"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  apiproject:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}apiproject
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
    ports:
      - "6000:80"
      - "6001:443"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ApiProject/Dockerfile
```

docker-compose.override.yml:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  checkoutpaymentgateway:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=helmet
      - ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx
    volumes:
      - ~/.aspnet/https:/https:ro
    ports:
      - "6000:80"
      - "6001:443"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same problem. The solution for me was to recreate docker-compose file, as I saw later, the problem was in **docker-compose.dcproj** file. It's auto-generated by VS file. Try to open this file, which is located in the parent directory of your project with any text editor and check  tag. In my situaton it was : {Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}/{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}/swagger. I removed {Scheme}://localhost:{ServicePort}/{Scheme}***://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}***/swagger . To decide this problem you can chech this tag, or just regenerate docker-compose in VS.